# How does DDR3 RAM Keep up with the processor if the processor is 3* as fast?

Tags: fetch, ram, processor

As processors fetch for all instructions from RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up [CPU Caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache). This is the classic way.